# Remove variable part of string in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, variables, substring, workbench

Halo all.

I have a table with two columns. One of them with customer_id and another one with acceptence_reason. I want to delete the customer_id from the acceptance part but have not yet come up with a effective way to do so. 
To avoid confusion I have added a picture to clearify my problem

[image: Problem]

Comment: this is not clear. Is the string `Accept based on reasonXX` a _static_ one? or will it vary?

Comment: and the string `(customer id=xyz)` always trails the _reason text_ ????

Comment: It will vary. so there is a number of reasons different reasons.

Comment: A combination of `substr` and `instr` should get you desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you already tried `substr()` but maybe you didn't know `instr()`. So I would try that:

```
select Customer_id, substr(acceptance_reason, 0, instr(acceptance_reason,"(") ) as acceptance_reason from ...
```

Comment: I found a solution with  Replace(acceptance_reason, CONCAT('(customer_id=', customer_id, ')', '').
But your method worked as well.